# SSO Between Websphere Portal and .NET Application

Tags: websphere, portal, websphere-portal, jsr286, jsr168

What's the best way to configure SSO between a WebSphere Portal Portlet and a .NET application?

We are using WebSphere Portal 6.1.5 and the portlet should just redirect to the .NET application, but not require the user to login since they already did on portal.  Both Portal and .NET app are using same Active Directory(LDAP) for authentication.

Answer (score 0):

SPNEGO is a mechanism that is widely used in WebSphere and Windows for SSO. I am not sure about .Net applications but it is worth your time to explore and see if this would help you in achieving your needs.

Try this for some basic info on SPNEGO and WebSphere

http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/websphere/library/techarticles/0809_lansche/0809_lansche.html
Using same LDAP for authentication does not necessarily mean anything. In most of the SSO scenarios, not all the back end servers use the same LDAP repository. All i am trying to say here is that there is no strong co-relation between the LDAP server and SSO.

HTH
Manglu

Comment: Yes I've used SPNEGO for SSO between a Windows Desktop and portal, but not for a .net application.  I'll take a look at it again and verify if it can be used for what I need.  Thanks